# Include Python / Bokeh plot in PowerPoint presentation preserving data pop-ups

Tags: python, plotly, bokeh, plotly-python

If an EXCEL chart is pasted into a PowerPoint presentation as an EXCEL object, it is possible to hover the mouse over the line and see it's value.  My boss likes this feature.  I don't like having to do charts in EXCEL.

It is possible to get the same effect with bokeh or plotly, but as far as I am aware, that either relies on a stand-alone html file or a server instance.

Is it possible to paste a bokeh chart into a PowerPoint presentation preserving the feature that when you hover your mouse over a point, the value (and some other information) pops up?

Or is there another python solution that would allow this feature in PowerPoint (ppt is essential) while also allowing plots to be generated via code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output of Plotly in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67519747/output-of-plotly-in-powerpoint)

Comment: Hrmm... Only if there are no other python solutions. The hyperlink is not a workable option...

Answer (score 0):

An available option is to create powerpoints with Plotly: https://towardsdatascience.com/embed-interactive-plots-in-your-slides-with-plotly-fde92a5865a and https://evidencen.com/how-to-embed-plotly-graphs-in-powerpoint/

Also it seems this question has been asked before and you can hyperlink the HTML source in the .pptx file: [Output of Plotly in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67519747/output-of-plotly-in-powerpoint)

Answer (score 0):

yes. it's a hover tool. [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool) is an example

Comment: Thanks @kagan.  I do know that it is possible to do this with bokeh via a stand-along html file or a server instance as per the question.  But can this be preserved pasting into PowerPoint?  I haven't managed to get this working inside a powerpoint slide...

Comment: @brb no, you cant do that. However, you could give a link or standalone screenshots.